# How can I find the shortest path in a 2D matrix, so that it avoids certain coordinates? C++

Tags: c++, matrix, breadth-first-search

I have seen similar questions to this asked before, but I have yet to find a solution that works for me. I have a 2D vector matrix initialized with 0's. An 'S' character denotes the starting point, an 'E' character denotes the exit point and an 'X' character denotes an obstacle. The object is to move S to E while avoiding X. I understand that BFS works with graphs, however I am unsure how to implement this with a matrix.

Here is BFS Search that I used in a program with a graph:

```
void Graph::BFS(int s, int d)
{
  // Mark all the vertices as not visited
  bool *visited = new bool[V];
  int trail[V];
  for(int i = 0; i < V; i++){
     visited[i] = false;
     trail[i] = -1;

  }
  // Create a queue for BFS
  list<int> queue;

  // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
  visited[s] = true;
  queue.push_back(s);

  // 'i' will be used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
  list<int>::iterator i;

  while(!queue.empty())
  {

    // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
    s = queue.front();
    if(s == d){

        break;
    }
    else

    queue.pop_front();

    // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
    // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it visited
    // and enqueue it
    for(i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i)
    {
        if(!visited[*i])
        {
            visited[*i] = true;
            queue.push_back(*i);
            trail[*i] = s;
        }

    }

   }
   int x = d;
   while(x != -1){

   cout<<x<<endl;
   x = trail[x];


   }  
}
```

This prints out the path. Is there a way to modify this to work for a matrix?

*Note: I'd like the path to include diagonals when appropriate.

```
Example Matrix:
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  S  0  0  0  0  X  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  X  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  X  E  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `BFS` function has a memory leak and uses non-standard (read, invalid) C++ syntax if `V` is a variable: `int trail[V];`

Comment: It sounds like you're still talking about a graph. It's simply being presented to you as a matrix, so you can consider there to be an edge between adjacent elements (and diagonals too if you wish.) Then you can just disregard edges that point to a disallowed cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a BFS.

for each cell, mark it as soon as you get to it and go to all possible directions (not marked) and set the correct distance between them and the start cell (it's easy to compute since it's a BFS).

everytime you get to a cell you can't go through, just return from it.

a pseudocode could be like:

```
void BFS(int i, int j, int currentDistance){
    mark[i][j] = true
    dist[i][j] = currentDistance
    if this cell is forbidden, return;

    let S be the set with all possible pairs (x,y) possible to go
    for each (x,y) in S:
        if( !mark[x][y] ) BFS(x, y, currentDistance + 1)
end
```

your answer will be dist[i][j].

you can easily verify if its possible to get there initializing all the possible distances with some big value.

when you return from a forbidden cell you guarantee that the way to the end will not come from it.